# Finding a basis for a set

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

We have a set $R_\omega := \{f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} \}$ of “infinite tuples."  Let $R_\infty$ denote the subspace of $R_\omega$ consist of all $f \in R_\omega$ such that $f(i) = 0$ for all but finitely many values of $i$. Find a basis for $R_\infty$.

I have shown that $R_w$ is a vector space under addition and scalar multiplication and proved that $R_\infty$ is a vector subspace of $R_w$. I am not sure if these two things will help me find a basis and would the basis be of $w$-dimensional?

Comment: It does not make sense to say that a basis is $ \omega $-dimensional.  Do you mean, the basis is infinite?  If that's what you mean, then yes.  It will be.  

Have you tried writing down some examples of elements in $ R_\omega $?  If you take the time to understand what these objects are, I think it will become clear how to find a basis for them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the set that f(i)=0 for all but one element and the value of non-zero is 1 is a basis.

Comment: can you explain a bit thanks

Comment: $R_{\infty}$ is set with finite non-zero items and it could be represent as finite numbers of linear combination of the basis.